# Unable to find the Job in apex job and who scheduled

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I have a scheduled job that run on every tuesday. However, somehow it ran on saturday but there is no job Id coming up in Apex Jobs  and I do not know how the job ran as per the schedule it should only execute on Tuesday.

I have two questions:

1. How do I find who ran the job on unknown day?
2. Why does the job id not appear in Apex Jobs?

Comment: A little forward...best not to call out specific members of the community in your posts or comments if they haven't already chimed in.

Comment: This increases chances of other members wouldn't like to answers as you are expecting a specific's answer. Indirectly.